# Django do I use query or url path to pass a parameter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

If I have two urls:

```
url(r'^maker/$', views.maker_list) #lists a car makers
url(r'^model/$', views.model_list) #lists of car models
```

If I click on the URL for models it gives me a list of models.
If I click on the URL for makers it gives me a list of makers.

I was thinking if I click on a maker e.g. CarMaker I want it to take me to a subset of all models ie. the ones that are made by the maker eg. CarMaker.

Is the best way to have it in the path like `model/CarMaker/` or as a query like `model/?maker=CarMaker`.

I have read if its unique put it in the path, however, this feels like a search/refinement, which are queries. I am a bit confused where to draw the line.

## Side question:

Should it be `model/CarMaker/` or `CarMaker/model/`?

Comment: you probably want `make/model` because `makes` determines what `models` you have.

Comment: Putting it in the URL is better in terms of having clean URLs and also the regex validation is done by Django for you. Other than that it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Because models are under makers, the url should be something like this:

```
/maker/<maker_id>/models
```

But if you don't have the id and you are just filtering by name, using a `GET` parameter seems like the correct option to me:

```
/models?maker=bmw
```

Hope it helps!